# why I am getting this error:"Received bad response from Model Management Service:\nResponse Code: 403\" while trying to de

Tags: python, azure-machine-learning-service

This is my code which I am trying to deploy my model on Azure AML:

```
aciconfig = AciWebservice.deploy_configuration(
            cpu_cores=1,
            memory_gb=1,
            tags={"data":"nlp classifier"},
            description='nlp cLASSIFICATION  MODEL'
            )

inference_config = InferenceConfig(entry_script="scoringscript.py", environment=myenv)

service = Model.deploy(workspace=ws,
                name='nlpse',
                models=[model],
                inference_config=inference_config,
                deployment_config=aciconfig, 
                overwrite = True)
service.wait_for_deployment(show_output=True)
url = service.scoring_uri
print(url)
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
WebserviceException: WebserviceException:
    Message: Received bad response from Model Management Service:
Response Code: 403
Headers: {'Server': 'nginx/1.22.1', 'Date': 'Fri, 25 Nov 2022 19:33:11 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'x-ms-client-request-id': 'dff1b808-aa1c-4b6d-9bf4-0b43325131b2', 'x-ms-client-session-id': '07e975c4-02fa-47ce-8ee6-cd2f808d53c1', 'api-supported-versions': '1.0, 2018-03-01-preview, 2018-11-19', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains; preload', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'x-aml-cluster': 'vienna-centralus-01', 'x-request-time': '0.630', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'}
Content: b'{"code":"Forbidden","statusCode":403,"message":"Forbidden","details":[{"code":"UserError","message":"KeyVaultErrorException encountered. Operation returned an invalid status code \'Forbidden\'"}],"correlation":{"RequestId":"dff1b808-aa1c-4b6d-9bf4-0b43325131b2"}}'
    InnerException None
    ErrorResponse 
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Received bad response from Model Management Service:\nResponse Code: 403\nHeaders: {'Server': 'nginx/1.22.1', 'Date': 'Fri, 25 Nov 2022 19:33:11 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'x-ms-client-request-id': 'dff1b808-aa1c-4b6d-9bf4-0b43325131b2', 'x-ms-client-session-id': '07e975c4-02fa-47ce-8ee6-cd2f808d53c1', 'api-supported-versions': '1.0, 2018-03-01-preview, 2018-11-19', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains; preload', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'x-aml-cluster': 'vienna-centralus-01', 'x-request-time': '0.630', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'}\nContent: b'{\"code\":\"Forbidden\",\"statusCode\":403,\"message\":\"Forbidden\",\"details\":[{\"code\":\"UserError\",\"message\":\"KeyVaultErrorException encountered. Operation returned an invalid status code \\'Forbidden\\'\"}],\"correlation\":{\"RequestId\":\"dff1b808-aa1c-4b6d-9bf4-0b43325131b2\"}}'"
    }
}
```

How can i resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

- I tried to reproduce the issue and it worked for me.

```
aciconfig = AciWebservice.deploy_configuration(
cpu_cores=1,
memory_gb=1,
tags={"data":"nlp classifier"},
description='nlp  cLASSIFICATION MODEL'
)
inference_config = InferenceConfig(entry_script="scoringscript.py", environment=myenv)
service = Model.deploy(workspace=ws,
name='nlpse',
models=[model],
inference_config=inference_config,
deployment_config=aciconfig,
overwrite = True)
service.wait_for_deployment(show_output=True)
url = service.scoring_uri
print(url)
```

- From the above code block,`service.wait_for_deployment(show_output=True)` is being called initially when the code block starts executing. It is taking the pipeline to wait for the long duration and hence it is detaching the connection after the TTL.
- `service.wait_for_deployment(show_output=True)` -> After getting the config and service details, then we need to execute the service wait method. It will solve the connection error.